# Doctrine ORM in Silex : persist not working

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, silex

I have a problem with Doctrine ORM in Silex. I am able to get some data but unable to save an entity in my database.

This is my configuration of Doctrine ORM :

```
$app['em'] = function ($app) {
    $params = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dbname' => 'beacon_prototype',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => '****',
        'password' => '****',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
    );

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/Domain"), true);

    $driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), array(__DIR__."/src/Domain"));

    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    $em = EntityManager::create($params, $config);

    return $em;
};
```

I can get some object in my Controller with :

```
$room = $app['em']->getRepository('Generic\Domain\Room')->findById($room_id);
```

But when I try to add a row in my database, it doesn't work.

```
$booking = new Booking();
$booking->setEventName($event_name);
$booking->setRoom($room);
$booking->setUser($user);
$booking->setEventStart($event_start);
$booking->setEventEnd($event_end);

$app['em']->persist($booking);
$app['em']->flush();
```

This is my Booking model :

```
namespace Generic\Domain;
```

use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * Generic\Domain\Booking
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="booking")
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="booking", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Room", inversedBy="booking", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="room_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $room;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    public $event_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    public $event_start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    public $event_end;
```

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Weird I have nearly the same config and everything works perfectly fine.
My config

```
$settings = $c->get('settings')['doctrine'];

$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    $settings['meta']['entity_path'],
    $settings['meta']['auto_generate_proxies'],
    $settings['meta']['proxy_dir'],
    $settings['meta']['cache'],
    false
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($settings['connection'], $config);
```